# Where to host large files without limit?

Tags: html, video, hosting

I'm looking for a way to host MP4, OGG and WEMB movies (HTML5 videos) (each is like 5-15MB large) externally.

Can you recommend some free services like Dropbox? Dropbox has bandwidth limits unfortunately and I'd like to be able to show those movies to at least 100-200 people daily.

Can you recommend any services?

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: why not youtube? Do you have to limit who can see your videos, or have to make your users see your own video player?

Comment: @Rotem I'm coding right now and testing videos that Dropbox has just blocked. There must be connection then :) Answer to this question might be useful to community.

Answer (score 2):

[Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/).  Its built for this.

<sub>(I joke not)</sub>

Comment: Not for HTML5 videos in those 3 formats. I use YouTube/Vimeo, too.

Comment: @Flow you can embed the Youtube player in your own pages.  It takes care of playback on all platforms.

Comment: I'm building website with YouTube/Vimeo AND HTML5 videos support. I'm looking for a way to host HTML5 videos without limits then.

Comment: Hmm... Quite difficult to find that host. I believe you need to purchase VPS or dedicated server. If shared hosting, you dont allowed to upload large video to your folder. It will make instability on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I have had great results using Amazon S3 for this. Just make sure you check the little box in the S3 dashboard that makes the file public.